# Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, admob

I am trying to build EAS app to use `react-native-google-mobile-ads`

Here is I did:

```
expo init
expo install expo-dev-client
expo install react-native-google-mobile-ads
eas prebuild
```

modified app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "testing-new-eas",
    "slug": "testing-new-eas",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.basselturky.testingneweas"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "3807fdfa-75de-4baf-8e76-951ee8dc5d70"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-************",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-************"
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT" android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-***my_ad_id***"/>
```

I built it with `eas build --profile development -p android`

Installed the APK file on my android emulator,
then `expo start --dev-client`

Every time I start the app, it crashes and I get this error on Android Studio Logcat.

I even tried AdMob test IDs, but it keeps saying "`Invalid application ID.`"

Logcat error:

```
   --------- beginning of crash
2022-10-12 03:38:24.531 8638-8638/com.basselturky.testingneweas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.basselturky.testingneweas, PID: 8638
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to find your app ID.                                                       *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to find your app ID.                                                       *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzee.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.2.0:22)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.2.0:1)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
            ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing this Crash/Error.

I used Ad ID from AdMob Ad unit instead of App ID in app.json

Solution:

Changed this:

```
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ad unit id", <------ This
    "ios_app_id": "ad unit id"
  }
```

With this:

```
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "app id", <------ With this
    "ios_app_id": "app id"
  }
```

Sorry for the inconvenience :)

and only these steps are required for EAS build,

```
expo init
expo install expo-dev-client
expo install react-native-google-mobile-ads
```

Edit app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
   ...
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "your app id",
    "ios_app_id": "your app id"
  }
}
```

```
eas build --profile development -p android
```